# Slice from images of a particular class in TensorFlow Datasets

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

So, I've been using TensorFlow datasets to build my models upon, and I'm trying to observe the effect of my model on Imbalanced data. To start it off, I wanted to create an imbalanced version of the Dogs vs Cats. So basically it has 12500 of dogs and cats each, but I want to take only 10% of the cat class when I'm loading the dataset. How do I configure the `split` argument in the `load` function for the dataset?

```
tfds.load('cats_vs_dogs')
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at
https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/splits
and
https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/cats_vs_dogs
it seems like there is no way to do what you want with the split option. You'll have to load the dataset, and manually remove some of the cats/add extra dogs.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Can you tell me a little bit about how I can do the latter? The files are loaded as tfrecords so how do I make changes to that?